# How to call a TimePicker from DIalogFragment?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have a Fragment, and a button "Settings" for example. When user presses this button, a DialogFragment "Settings" appeared. And from this "SettingsDialogFragment" I want to call a TimePicker, which is also a DialogFragment. How can I do that if my fragment extends a Fragment class, but not FragmentActivity class?

Comment: Use the hosting `Activity` as a middle man: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html

Answer (score 0):

Just open a TimePickerDialog in one of the button listeners of the DialogFragment.